# Using VLOOKUP in an IF Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Is it possible to use VLOOKUP in an if statement so that if VLOOKUP returns a certain value some action should be taken?  I tried:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,G$4:$H$147,0)<>0,1,0)
```

and

```
=IF(VALUE(VLOOKUP(A2,G$4:$H$147,0))<>0,1,0)
```

but neither was successful.

Comment: For reference, it helps people (including yourself) answer questions if you specify *how* the formulas were not successful. Did they return an error? Which one? Did they return something different than what you expected? What did they return? This information is often vital to getting a useful answer, this case notwithstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VLOOKUP function is missing a parameter. The third parameter should specify the column index (in the range in the second parameter) you want to return a value from. I assume you want the value from column `H`, so your function should be the following:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,G$4:$H$147,2,FALSE)<>0,1,0)
```

[More info on VLOOKUP from Microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)